# How to use python+stackdriver to query idle instances in gcp google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can we query those bulk idle vm in GCP? Next I want shutdown or destroy them. I suppose we can refer uptime and load average to judge the idle resource. Here i cloned this sample:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/monitoring/api/v3/uptime-check-client
It didn't give me useful information.

```
python snippets.py -h
    list-uptime-check-configs
    list-uptime-check-ips
    create-uptime-check
    get-uptime-check-config
    delete-uptime-check-config
    update-uptime-check-config
```

Tried all above commands, but how can i get all vm uptime list in my gcp project?

We have many projects in Google Cloud, each project running hundreds of instances,  these instances are frequently creation or destroy  in my team. Tester will delete instance once test job done. These instance created by testers, and create them in the future if needed. But if the user forgot delete it, then it's a wast.  So we want find out those idle instance and destroy them, and then save money.

Comment: Have you referred the [idle recommendation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-and-applying-idle-vm-recommendations) provided by Compute Engine?

Comment: thanks. We tried this command `gcloud recommender recommendations list \
  --project=PROJECT-ID \
  --location=ZONE \
  --recommender=google.compute.instance.IdleResourceRecommender \
  --format=yaml` But it can get rarely idle vms, only show 1 or 2 vm instance idle which already deleted. Even tried `gcloud beta recommender recommendations`, same no useful output.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), so that a Google team member can help you with your investigation

Comment: Thanks Adebisi, submitted issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155690298